# ROS noetic, fatal error: ros/ros.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, publish-subscribe, ros

I'm trying to start a c++ script (simply the listener from the ROS [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29), just with the name subpub.cpp) but I get the error "fatal error: ros/ros.h: No such file or directory".

I tried looking at the old questions about this, but they don't seem to work for me.

I am using noetic on ubuntu, and the catkin_make does not give any errors.

this is my packege.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>infoexc</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The infoexc package</description>
  <maintainer email="cnr@todo.todo">cnr</maintainer>
  <license>TODO</license>
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>rospy</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>std_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>rospy</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
  <export>
    <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->
  </export>
</package>
```

and this is my CMakeLists.txt  file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(infoexc)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_executable(subpub scripts/C++/subpub.cpp)
target_link_libraries(subpub ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

Scripts in c++ are in /catkin_ws/src/infoexc/scripts/C++, everything worked fine in python.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the error is related to 'Visual Studio code', I should add the libraries to the path I think, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

With ROS I always built it from the commandline.

```sh
cd /path/to/your/catkin_ws && source devel/setup.bash && catkin_make
```

You need to source your project and then call `catkin_make`, that should create a build and be able to link `ros.h`.